# Is the indefinite integral of a piecewise continuous function a continuous function?

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals, piecewise-continuity

I had looked around on the web and can't find much information related to the integration of piecewise continuous functions.

Let's say we have a simple function

$$f(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      0 & x\leq 0 \\
      x & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
      0 & x>1
\end{cases}$$

and we are looking to find the integral $\int f(x) dx$

WolframAlpha gives me the following result:

$$\int f(x) dx=
\begin{cases} 
      c & x\leq 0 \\
      \frac{x^2}{2}+c & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
      \frac{1}{2}+c & x>1
\end{cases}$$

The cases $x\leq 0$ and $0\leq x\leq 1$ are clear. But why do we need the $\frac{1}{2}$ for the $x>1$ case? I see that this makes the integral continuous but is it necessary, i.e. is it wrong to have simply $c$ for the $x>1$ case for the integral?

Comment: Maybe the reason is that if you want to calculate $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ with $b>1$ you can just insert the upper limit, and it will be correct.

Comment: But $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ with $b>1$ evaluates to just $\int_a^1 f(x) dx$ doesn't it? So there is no difference whether you have the $\frac{1}{2}$ or not.

Comment: Well, yes, but since the $1/2$ is there, one could equally well think of it as inserting the upper limit at $x=b$ instead of $x=1$, in the spirit of $\int_a^bf(x)\,dx=F(b)-F(a)$ where $F$ is a primitive of $f$.

Comment: There is a reason why they are called INDEFINITE integrals!

Comment: Actually, you say that it is clear for $x\leq 0$, but it is really the same thing happening there. Why choose $c$ and not $3+c$ or $-4+c$? It is choosen so that you get continuity at $x=0$. Again, it fits well with $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ with $a<0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is no. An indefinite integral is not a continuous function, because an indefinite integral is not a function. However, once you fix $a\in \mathbb{R}$, 
$$\int_a^x f(t)dt$$
is  a continuous function. Note that once we fix $a$, the constant of integration is completely determined.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the indefinite integral of a continuous function is a family of continuous functions. If you want to find exactly one of these functions, you have to fix an initial condition $F(x_0) = C_0$.

If you want to obtain the same function obtained by WolframAlpha, solve for the following equalities: [lateral limits](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nNBn7.jpg)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 0):

> > $$f(x)=
> > \begin{cases} 
> >       0 & x< 0 \\
> >       x & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
> >       0 & x>1
> > \end{cases}$$ [image]
>
> WolframAlpha gives me the following result:
> $$\int f(x) \,\mathrm dx=
> \begin{cases} 
>       C & x< 0 \\
>       \frac{1}{2}x^2+C & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
>       \frac{1}{2}+C & x>1
> \end{cases}$$

$f$ has a jump discontinuity at $1,$ so has no antiderivative at $1,$ so has no indefinite integral (its complete set of antiderivatives), so Wolfram's result is technically incorrect.

However, for $$g(x)=
\begin{cases} 
      0 & x< 0 \\
      x & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
     \color{brown}1 & x>1
\end{cases},$$ [image]

we do have $$\int g(x) \,\mathrm dx=
\begin{cases} 
      C & x< 0 \\
      \frac{1}{2}x^2+C & 0\leq x\leq 1 \\
      \color{brown}{x-\frac{1}{2}+C} & x>1
\end{cases}.$$

> why do we need the $\frac{1}{2}$ for the $(x>1)$ case? I see that this makes the integral continuous but is it necessary ?

Every antiderivative is by definition differentiable, and thus continuous. In other words, every instantiation of (i.e., for each value of $C$) every indefinite integral must be continuous. (Therefore, for each antiderivative with an interval domain, the vertical shifts of its various pieces depend on one another; here, adjusting the $(x>1)$ case by `-½` ensures that the antiderivatives are continuous.)